# How to solve async-await function problem while using Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I want to use axios using async await function.

But when I use async await function then I get an error.

```
useEffect(async() => {
   await axios
        .get("https://cryptic-inlet-27003.herokuapp.com/products?size=6")
        .then((data) => setItems(data.data));
}, []);
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: If you use `.then`, you don't have to `async/await`

Comment: dont make use of `.then` if using async await either use promises or use async await

Comment: This is a mix of async/await and promises--pick one. When there's an error it's useful to include the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both promises and async/await at the same time either use `.then()` or use async/await:
Here I have shown how you can do this using promises:

#### Edit: this will actually turn out to give an error because making api requests from useeffect is not permitted so this answer is wrong

```js
useEffect(async() => {
axios.get("https://cryptic-inlet-27003.herokuapp.com/products?size=6")
  .then(function (response) {
    setItems(response.data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })}, [])
```

Here I am using async await:

```js
useEffect(async() => {
    let response = await axios.get("https://cryptic-inlet- 
    27003.herokuapp.com/products?size=6")
    setItems(response.data);
}, [])
```

Comment: This is actually wrong. You'll get an error message such as...

Warning: useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.

More on this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-do-data-fetching-with-hooks

Comment: @Amechi k i made the change i just noticed this issue thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using promises and async/await at the same time. Async/await is nothing but sugar coating of promises. You can read more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get("https://cryptic-inlet-27003.herokuapp.com/products?size=6")
   // do something with data!
};
useEffect(async() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: "*The issue is that you're using promises and async/await at the same time.*" why would that be an issue? It can be misleading for people who would maintain the code, however, on technical level the code is valid.

Comment: Also, note that the code you've provided *is* problematic. 1. using `async` without `await` is an indication for something wrong. (both functions) 2. not awaiting the axios call in  `fetchData()` means the promise is being destructured 3. `fetchData()` does not return anything 4. Even then, the result from the call to `fetchData()` is not used at all.

Comment: @VLAZ I forgot to add await in the fetchData. That was my bad. Secondly, it's not important that fetchData should return something. It's just good practice to not add async/await or promises inside the useeffect. `The issue is that you're using promises and async/await at the same time.` -- I guess I misspoke, It's not an issue but still either you should use promises or async/await. It maintains readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a async await inside of useEffect because that is not a methodologic of react, you have that change your logic code to other, for example use **useState varaibles** and with the result of axios you will update the **useState varaibles**, something like that:

```
const [items, setItems]=useState({})//any

useEffect(async() => {
   axios
        .get("https://cryptic-inlet-27003.herokuapp.com/products?size=6")
        .then((data) => setItems(data.data));
}, []);

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(items, 'this items changed')
  //to do...
}, [items])
```

or

```
const [items, setItems]=useState({})//any

async function requestAxios(){
  const data=await axios.get("https://cryptic-inlet-27003.herokuapp.com/products?size=6")
  setItems(data.data)
}

useEffect(async() => {
   requestAxios()
}, []);

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(items, 'this items changed')
  //to do...
}, [items])
```